Spring boot Bcrypt Password in application.properties
I want to store a BCrypt-hashed password in application.properties for datasource.password and establish a MySQL database connection. Is this feasible? Is there any way to configure Spring so that I can put a BCrypt-hashed password in application.properties, and Spring internally decrypts it to establish the datasource connection?
I tried jasypt and cipher but both the way any one can decrypt and get to know the password I don't want like that I want to prevent anyone from decrypting the password, meaning I am looking for a one-way solution, like how BCrypt works, where the password is hashed rather than encrypted.

Shouldn't the passwords be externally injected from environment variables?

No if I use environment variable then in production environment when I deploy a jar file it might create problem can't use that approach

what you are asking won't work for simple reason that at the end of the day, to connect to DB you need to provide your password in plaintext. So one way solutions like BCrypt won't work. Your idea of storing and using the already converted value (hash) is actually just as bad as using a plain text password since the whole point of storing hash values in the database is to avoid hackers from being able to use them in case they are stolen (since you still need to use the original plain text to authenticate). If someone could use hash to login then hashing becomes useless

Yes, you are correct, but I want to implement this in such a way that no one, not even someone with access to the code, can know the database password in my application.

All kind of passwords should be stored in environment variables. Having them in jar compromises your application. Passwords not matter how strongly encrypted but exposed in application are secured by present standards only. In your specific case you should secure access to database server only within the private network. In addition within the network you can further restrict database server/client access with kyestore/trustore.

You can manually initialize the DataSource object in the code. I hope this helps you:
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String encryptedPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String decryptedPassword = encryptedPassword.replace("{bcrypt}", "");

        // Verify and decrypt the password (assuming the original password is correct).
        if (passwordEncoder.matches("your_plain_password", decryptedPassword)) {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
            dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
            dataSource.setPassword(decryptedPassword);
            return dataSource;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Password mismatch");
        }
    }
}


In this case, anyone can potentially retrieve the MySQL password by using this class or by using a debugger, which means the purpose of encryption is not fully achieved.

If you don't want any passwords to appear in the code, it is recommended to store the database connection information in an external configuration file rather than hardcoding it into the code. You can even configure it in environment variables to avoid password leakage in the source code.

While storing sensitive information such as database credentials in environment variables can improve security, it may create challenges during the production build process. Specifically, managing environment variables properly can be tricky when deploying to different environments, especially when they need to be securely configured for each build or deployment. Without proper handling, there is a risk of misconfiguration or the credentials being exposed if the environment variables are not properly secured or managed during deployment.

According to what you said, even with a secure one-way encryption method, the encryption logic and keys would still be exposed in the program.

I am looking for a solution where the password in application.properties is stored in BCrypted form for the DB connection, but I don't want to expose the original password anywhere in the code.

I believe you can try starting from MySQL, that is, by using MySQL to assign permission to a user and then set the remote access address for that user to only your application’s address. This way, even if others know your password, they won't be able to log in to your database.

This is not possible because client manages db servers I just want to restrict application level is there any way to do this ?
